# calling sync call before async call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

I have a certain situation here, and wanted to see the best outcome of the approach using design patterns and OOPS concept.

I have a "web-service" call which if called with different parameter lets say "bed", "car", and "toy". For right now lets keep these parameters as const and they never change when making calls.

Hence, based on those three parameters, it can be only one selected, and passed through the web-service call.

The web-service call, initially have been constructed as a "Class method". As, the whole idea was simply to get the value, make a nsurlRequest, get the data, parse and return it back in NSDictionary form.

Now, the business requirement have got changed, and "car", and "bed" requires additional "web-service" calls, based on what "accessories" they require, and chosen if the customer needs it or not, proceed's the first web-service call.

Thus, if you notice this is somewhat of a waterfall methodology, as the second service call is required to complete prior the first one in order to proceed.

Based on the above scenario, what could be a better approach to handle such situation?

I have thought about using "Class delegates", without changing much of the construction of the class, but just wanted to get much clear understanding if there can be any better approach.

I can't use GCD here, as this is being used for iOS 3.0 as well.

I am using NSRunloop mechanism for now with 10 seconds delay, but feel's like its not a good approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless this is an internal app for a place using lots of old devices, there is no reason to support iOS 3.x. Most new apps shouldn't even bother with 4.x. Do yourself a favor and drop 3.x support. You gain so much and lose virtually 0% potential customers.

Comment: @rmaddy, this isn't my decision, wished I could do that, but its for commercial use.

Comment: If you are still targeting iOS 3, then you will probably be on your own.  Good luck.